# Starting sequence in PFC AND SMPS Design

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

In the design of power supplies, we often use Active PFC and downstrem SMPS, to regulate the output voltage, and  we often use IC controllers like MC33262 for PFCs and NCP1252 for AC-DC converters. These IC require a DC input voltage as VCC.

If we take the example of MC33262,that needs a VCC of 12V, and used as a PFC in a 230 Vrms in a main line to feed a flyback converter as downstream SMPS, how do we get this VCC=12V in the starting sequence when the only existent voltage is the full-wave rectified one ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your goals and budget.

Simple products have some form of trickle-charge start-up circuitry to kickstart the switching. Once the switching starts, some of the energy intended for the main rail is harvested to power the logic more efficiently, often via an ancillary winding.

There are also primary-side DC/DC buck converters (by Power Integrations and other vendors) which produce a loosely-regulated rail by bucking the bulk DC rail down to 12V. This is sufficient for simple applications as well.

When you're considering both a PFC and a DC/DC converter, you will have fairly significant power consumption on the primary VCC rail. In this case, a standalone auxiliary DC/DC converter which operates over a wide voltage range becomes a better choice. These tend to be flyback converters. A transformer-based solution like a flyback allows you to not only have a primary-side rail for your PFC and DC/DC, but a secondary-side rail for any ancillary control logic. It also operates independently of your main output and PFC stage, which is critical for high-reliability power supplies which communicate with a backplane. This scheme has its own trickle-charge startup circuitry (often part of the control IC itself).

Answer (score 3):

When you associate a PFC with a downstream circuitry, you have to think about the start-up sequence depending on how the downstream converter operates:

1. if it is a universal-mains design, e.g. a flyback converter accepting to operate down to 85 V rms by design, then it can start-up first and once its auxiliary power is alive, it powers the PFC circuit. This is a very common practice.
2. there are converters that do not lend themselves well to a universal input range. Forward and LLCs are among these converters and the PFC *must* start first before cranking the second converter. A small logic glue is thus necessary to ensure this synchronization between both converters.

I have often seen both control sections (PFC and forward) powered by the same \$V_{cc}\$ rail but the forward PWM was kept silent until the PFC output voltage was stabilized (PFCs can be prone to start-up overshoots considering the low bandwidth). A simple timer started after the PFC is powered is usually good enough or, if available, the brown-out input of the PWM controller selected for the forward can also be used for that purpose.

A final note, the MC33262 is a venerable PFC controller launched after the 33261 during the MOT era. If it works well, it no longer meets all safety criteria required for new designs. Beside, I would recommend to implement a charge-pump around the auxiliary winding rather than a peak rectification as shown in the 262 data-sheet. This voltage is highly variable with the mains while you can keep it stable in an easier way with a charge-pump. See the below circuit excerpted from [here](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/EVBUM2049-D.PDF):

[image]

*disclaimer*: beside writing articles and publishing books, I also work for a semi company :-)

Answer (score 2):

> *how do we get this VCC=12V in the starting sequence when the only
> existent voltage is the full-wave rectified one ?*

The data sheet on page 11 and 12 shows how: -

[image]

12 volts is just a nominal value - providing you don't dump more than 30 mA into pin 8 you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

> how do we get this VCC=12V in the starting sequence when the only existent voltage is the full-wave rectified one ?

In a number of devices I have examined, there is a low power resistor/zener pair that is used to provide just enough regulated current to bootstrap the other components. I can't say how universal that practice is.